# looping with cin inside the loop, thus storing different char*s in an array (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, cin

I'm writing a basic program in C++ that creates a student database (name, major and GPA for each student). The user enters how many students will be in the database, and then enters the data items for each student one by one.

I made a loop that executes "x student" number of times and adds the students one by one to an array of Students by calling `cin.getline` for each data item and then creating an instance of Student with these items which it adds to the array in the next available place.

`Name` and `major` are `char*` variables (they cannot be strings for this assignment).

I'm having (I assume) pointer-based problems, because after putting a watch on the array of students, I realized that as soon as a new student is added to the array, every previous student in the array is set to the same data as the new student. I think it's because the names of the variables are always the same , since theyre in a loop, and I think that when I create a new Student object it keeps being put in the same address, thus changing all previous items in the array.

I have tried deleting the address of `newStudent`, and I've tried setting it to `NULL` after it adds a new student, but my program either breaks or the name and major in newStudent become lines of gibberish instead of deleting their content.

Here's the pertinent bits from main.cpp: (I removed the parts where I was trying to delete things and set things to `NULL` because they were making it worse and I don't know if I was on the right track). this is just the first part of main. it calls other functions later that I wrote, but I tested those and they all work fine. This is the part that's making it all break.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

int numMajors = 0;                  // keeps track of the total number of Majors
int currAdded = 0;                  // keeps track of how many students have been added THUS FAR
const int MAX_MAJORS = 100;         // max number of majors allowed
const int MAX_LENGTH = 25;          // max length of character array
const int TABLE_SIZE = 100;         // max table size
int numStudents = 0;                // total number of students being added
char* name = new char[MAX_LENGTH];  // cin>>name
char* major = new char[MAX_LENGTH]; // cin>>major
float GPA = 0;                      // cin>>gpa

//Get Data
cout << "--Student Database Data Entry--" << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter the number of students in registry: ";
cin >> numStudents;

cout << endl << "Enter data for each student: " << endl;

Student table[TABLE_SIZE];
char* majors[MAX_MAJORS];

for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){

    cout << "    Student " << (i+1) << " : " << endl;
    cout << "        Last Name: ";

    // need to use getline to cin multiple words, so using
    // cin.ignore() to eat the trailing \n from cin>>numStudents

    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name, MAX_LENGTH);
    cout << "        Major: ";
    cin.getline(major, MAX_LENGTH);
    cout << "        GPA: ";
    cin >> GPA;

    Student* newStudent = new Student(name, major, GPA);

    table[i] = *newStudent;

    currAdded++;
```

and here is my constructors and destructor for `Student` (in `student.cpp`)

```
Student::Student() :
    name(NULL),
    major(NULL),
    GPA(0)
{
}

Student::Student(char* name, char* major, float GPA) :
    name(NULL),
    major(NULL),
    GPA(0)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->major = major;
    this->GPA = GPA;
}

Student::~Student()
{
    if(name)
        delete [] name;
    if(major)
        delete [] major;

}

Student& Student::operator=(Student& student)
{
    this->name = student.name;
    this->major = student.major;
    this->GPA = student.GPA;
    return *this;
}
```

note: when my destructor is called, it also fills the name and major variables it's supposed to be deleting with long strings of gibberish characters, but that's a whole other problem. I commented it out for a while to temporarily get around this problem but I realize that's not a long term solution (the two are probably related)

If there's any more code you'd like to see I would be happy to post it, I'm trying to keep this as short as I can and I'm not sure if more is necessary.

Thank you so much for your insight

Comment: Where is your constructor for `Student`? You have to copy the *strings* passed instead of just assigning the *pointers* passed.

Comment: @MikeCAT added, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy the *strings* passed instead of just assigning the *pointers* passed.

Try this:

```
#include <cstring> // for using strlen() and strcpy()

Student::Student(char* name, char* major, float GPA) :
    name(NULL),
    major(NULL),
    GPA(0)
{
    this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1]; // +1 for terminating null-character
    strcpy(this->name, name);
    this->major = new char[strlen(major) + 1];
    strcpy(this->major, major);
    this->GPA = GPA;
}
```

Comment: Also be careful not to delete what is still used. Define copy constructer and assignment operator properly if you will use them. It is also good to be careful not to cause memory leak, but not deleting what is no longer used is better than deleting what you need.